# How to set the selected option on a dropdown list on a jquery dialog?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a table of data, when I sent the a row of data to fields on a jQuery dialog it fails to set the selected value of the `dropdown list`.

I have used this:

```
 $('#ddlProducts').val(data.prodID);
```

`data.prodID` has a value but it does not set it to the `value` of the `dropdown`. How do I fix this?

The table is a jQuery `datatable`.

Comment: Have you checked the console for any error? Also make sure the value in the options tags matches the value in the val method.

Comment: Post your rendered `dropdown list / select tag` and the value of `data.prodID`.

Comment: Try this `$("<%= ddlProducts.ClientID %>").val(data.prodID);`

Comment: @TusharGupta not a single error

Comment: Sorry, it should be like this `$('#' + "<%= ddlProducts.ClientID %>").val(data.prodID);`.. The point is, your selector **might** be wrong. That's why you need to post your rendered `dropdown list / select tag` and the value of `data.prodID`.

Comment: @choz rendered drop down is dynamic... and in the console it shows the list accurately the problem i have is i cannot set it to another value aka ProdID of the row it always shows the default selection

Comment: I don't believe you. Post your `html select tags` for `ddlProducts` and javascript ajax call.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100748/discussion-between-phill-greggan-and-choz).

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

First you get your `select` tag.
Then you set it's `value` to the **`value`** of the desired option not it's `id`, you'll do it like this:

```
var data = {
   prodID : "id3",
   someOtherData: "foobar"
}
$('select').val($("#"+data.prodID).val());
```

if your HTML looks like this:

```
<select>
  <option id="id1" value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option id="id2" value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option id="id3" value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option id="id4" value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/Tarekis/2d269h0s/)

Comment: what i need to do is data is row of a jquery datatable it contains accurate data... i just need to assign the prodID to the dropdownlist so it will show the text of that

Comment: I have a hard time reading that, i'm sorry, you want to add another option to your select, is that right?

Comment: i need to set the selected value to that prodID

Comment: Okay, is it already one of the select's options? And your prodID is text since it does not reffer to an option or what exactly is it? You want to have "Some text" selected when your prodID is "Some text"?

Comment: the drop down has a text/value conbination prodID has the value i need to set to as teh selected

Comment: So i guess your situation looks just like [that](https://jsfiddle.net/Tarekis/02xtfre7/)? A option has a value and your prodID is exactly this value?

Comment: Then your CSS selector for your `select` or your `prodID` is wrong, no other options. Post your rendered markup and a sample data object.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $('select').val("mastercard");    // Select by value
    text1 = "sample";
    $("select option:contains(" + text1 + ")").attr('selected', 'selected'); // select by text
```